# Two onClick actions one button

Tags: javascript, html

Does someone know a wizards trick to make it work ?

```
<input type="button" value="Dont show this again! " onClick="fbLikeDump();" onclick="WriteCookie();" />
```

PS: I am using it in a .js file.

Answer (score 46):

Additional attributes (in this case, the second `onClick`) will be ignored. So, instead of `onclick` calling both `fbLikeDump();` and `WriteCookie();`, it will only call `fbLikeDump();`. To fix, simply define a single `onclick` attribute and call both functions within it:

```
<input type="button" value="Don't show this again! " onclick="fbLikeDump();WriteCookie();" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try it:

```
<input type="button" value="Dont show this again! " onClick="fbLikeDump();WriteCookie();" />
```

Or also

```
<script>
function clickEvent(){
    fbLikeDump();
    WriteCookie();
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Dont show this again! " onClick="clickEvent();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" value="..." onClick="fbLikeDump(); WriteCookie();" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your button an id something like this:

```
<input id="mybutton" type="button" value="Dont show this again! " />
```

Then use jquery (to make this unobtrusive) and attach click action like so:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#mybutton').click(function (){
       fbLikeDump();
       WriteCookie();
    });
});
```

(this part should be in your .js file too)

I should have mentioned that you will need the jquery libraries on your page, so right before your closing body tag add these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://PATHTOYOURJSFILE"></script>
```

The reason to add just before body closing tag is for performance of perceived page loading times