# Onclick - Multiple JavaScript Queries

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I've read and tried numerous suggestions from Stack Overflow but none worked for me, forcing me to ask in person.

Currently I use this code to show and hide some content, the id `tb1` is the `div` tag my content is wrapped in.

```
<input type="button" value="Information" onclick="javascript:sizeTbl('block');" />
<a href="javascript:sizeTbl('none');">(<i>Close</i>)</a>
```

The button is "Information" and I've added a clickable link that closes the content, because I can't get the button to register the `javascript:sizeTbl('none');">(<i>Close</i>)`

Can someone please tell me how to do this, I've tried simply adding the `javascript:sizeTbl('none');">(<i>Close</i>)` after the first `onclick` command like so:

```
onclick="javascript:sizeTbl('block');javascript:sizeTbl('none');"
```

but it doesn't work and I've also tried the below linked fixes but to no avail.

[How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/onclick-multiple-javascript-functions)

[Two onClick actions one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544520/two-onclick-actions-one-button)

In case it's needed here is the main JS that defines `tb1` etc.. I've also tried adding a new function directly in to that script (as I thought calling `tb1` outside might cause an issue)

```
function sizeTbl(h) {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
  tbl.style.display = h;
}
function sizeTb2(h) {
  var tb2 = document.getElementById('tb2');
  tb2.style.display = h;
}
function sizeTb3(h) {
  var tb3 = document.getElementById('tb3');
  tb3.style.display = h;
}
function sizeTb4(h) {
  var tb4 = document.getElementById('tb4');
  tb4.style.display = h;
}
$('#toggle-view').on('click', function() 
{
   var button = $(this);

   if ( button.hasClass('view-page')  ) 
   {
       ViewPage();
       button.removeClass('view-page');   
   } 
   else 
   {
        ViewMenu();
        button.addClass('view-page');
   }
});
```

Comment: Check your `else` statement again...

Comment: Java and JavaScript are unrelated.

Comment: Added jQuery tag to open up question to broader audience.

Comment: did the html input tag is in php file?

Comment: Okay, but I'm still really stuck with this... Can no one suggest anything?

Comment: Ok well I've posted it in Pastebin. - Basically I'm trying to remove the need for the (Close) button and get the button to show the content on one click and close it on the second. Not sure why you needed the full source as I gave you the relevant info in my question, anyway please see here: http://pastebin.com/q0vLBns4

Comment: Hi i'm not sure if this is what you were looking for, can you try this? http://jsfiddle.net/ByrFz/4/show ,[source](http://jsfiddle.net/ByrFz/4/)