# Open multiple Windows in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to `PHP` and trying to open multiple pages from a single link, such as https://www.google.co.uk, https://www.youtube.com and https://www.stackoverflow.com/ by using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16849479/7667220).

```
echo "<a href='https://www.google.co.uk' onclick=
window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com/');
return true;>multiopen</a>";
```

When running my code only the first two links, https://www.google.co.uk and https://www.youtube.com, open. the third link, https://www.stackoverflow.com/, **does not**.

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10544531/7667220) to execute multiple functions from one single attribute but I cannot seem to replicate the syntax in `PHP`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _Open multiple Windows in PHP..._ Has nothing todo with php

Comment: Apologies if my nomenclature is incorrect, could you please suggest an edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the anonymous function:

```
echo "<a href='https://www.google.co.uk' onclick=\"function(){
           window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
           window.open('https://www.stackoverflow.com/');
           return true;
   }\">multiopen</a>";
```

Comment: When trying the above code I get a syntax error, perhaps due to the use of " instead of ' before function and after the close brace? When I make these changes I no longer get a syntax error but the code does not work as intended.

Comment: i have escaped the double quotes, try now

Comment: This solved the syntax error but only the first link opens.

Comment: and isnt the broeser blocking the other window??? on my side firefox prevents that

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the first two links open as intended in my original code.

Comment: It turns out that the multiple browsers I tried only allowed for one 'pop-up' so disabling this was required. Also my initial code required the additional quotes which I was able to deduce from your answer and therefore I have accepted this as the answer.